# I need help to show VAT amount in datagridview correctly

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, datagridview

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFpAq.jpg)

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Qtty"].Index].Value) * 
                Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["PurchasePrice"].Index].Value));

        decimal sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
             sum += Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
        }

        decimal vatpct = 15m;
        decimal vat = Math.Round(sum - (sum / (1 + (vatpct / 100))), 2);

        decimal subtotal = Math.Round(sum - vat, 2);
        lblSubtotal.Text = subtotal.ToString();

        row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["VAT"].Index].Value =   ((sum * vat / 100));
    }
}
```

This is my code regarding my invoice design but it's not working as well about vat calculation.

Note: all prices here must be VAT included!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your life easy, put the data and the calculation into a datatable and bind it to the grid:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("InvoiceId");
dt.Columns.Add("ExVat", typeof(double));
dt.Columns.Add("IncVat", typeof(double)).Expression = "[ExVat] * 1.15";

someNewBlankDataGridViewOnYourForm.DataSource = dt;
```

As implied by the last line of code it's probably simplest if you put a new datagridview on your form and bind it to this datatable (set its DataSource property)

Now all you need to do is get the user to type the ID and ex vat amount. The inc vat amount will calculate automatically

Make your life even easier, add a new DataSet type of file to your project, add a table to it, add columns and set in the Designer all those things you see above (expression, datatype, name etc).. datatables made in this way are heaps easier to work with

Comment: Thanks @Caius
maybe it's easy for you to do that, but for me still, I have confuse about using data set with DGV and connecting with each other...acutlly I'm new in C# development 
so, if you can to write lines of code to help me with that as you said above
or help with my code here to do that

Comment: Can you define where the problems are that do not make the VAT appear correctly?

Comment: Quick run down then: A DataSet is a collection of DataTable and DataRelation. You aren't using a DataSet in this code. A DataTable is a collection of DataRow and DataColumn, kinda like a database. DataColumn either have values put in them or they calculate values based on other columns using the Expression property

Comment: When I said "add a DataSet" I meant to right click on your project in the Solution Explorer and choose Add New Item.. DataSet. You can then design all these settings visually. This is a different process to writing eg `var da = new DataSet();` - that creates a plain simple DataSet that is nowhere as feature rich as adding a DataSet file to the project and then designing it

Comment: It's kinda the same as when you add a Form. You can write in code `var f = new Form();` but that form is just empty etc. If you add a form as a file then open it you can design it fully etc, and you can look in the Form1.Designer.cs to see the hundreds of lines of code the form designer wrote for you. DataSet Files and designers are the same idea